# git - ignore specific folder from pulling

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to avoid **overwriting** specific folder in my git repo when executing `git pull` command. 
In my .gitignore file I have already specified the name of the folder which I wish to ignore.

However, when I execute **git pull** the content of the folder gets overwritten.

**Is there any parameter I can specific in my `git pull` command to ignore that folder?**

Comment: Rename the folder before pulling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `pull`, by default git will do a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.  It's the `merge` that may overwrite your working files.

You attempted to use `.gitignore`; as you've seen, this doesn't work.  That's because `.gitignore` does *not* tell your local repo to ignore what the remote has to say about the specified files.  It only says that *if* there is an untracked file at a specified path, that file should (by default) remain untracked.

syny's answer recommends that you `fetch` and then do a path-selective `checkout`.  This is only a possible solution if you know that the merge would be a fast-forward to the remote state - i.e. you have no local changes outside of the path you're "protecting" - because otherwise you're bypassing the merge and will overwrite your local changes.

Arpit's answer suggests `update-index --assume-unchanged`; it is a common misconception that this is applicable to a case like yours.  In fact, `--assume-unchanged` ha *very narrow application*.  (In fact, I've never used it.)  It's for when there's a large part of your work tree that you know you haven't modified relative to the index; and you want git to know not to waste time checking for modifications in that part of the work tree (e.g. during `status` or maybe even `add`) - presumably because your filesystem is slow.  It dose *not* mean that a pull or merge should assume the path is unchanged, and in fact it would cause these operations to error out.

If you have a standing need to keep the local versions of the files in this directory, you have two choices:

1) Change your local workflow so that your git work tree is free to just be your git work tree.  Situations like you describe often arise if you're trying to checkout directly to a production folder; in which case if you consider putting a "build process" or "deployment process" in the pipeline, then you could check out exactly what's in the repo then copy what's needed to the production folder.

2) Look up "sparse checkout" and see if it can be configured to meet your needs, by specifying that a checkout in the local repo should never include the directory you want to protect.

On the other hand, if this is a one-off checkout that happens to need to leave some files alone this one time, then it's probably a lot easier to just copy the local versions to a backup location, do the pull, and copy the files back.

Comment: I did what you suggested by manually copying the file as that seemed to be the only solution. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

`git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`

I solve this problem with `fetch` command. Like that :

```
git fetch {remote}
// git fetch will download all the recent changes, but it will not put it in your current checked out code (working area).
```

and checkout files except your ignoring file :

```
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- !(file)
//git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- !(file) will checkout the all files except your ignoring from the the downloaded changes .
```

and than you can :

```
git add 
git commit
```